How to crate navigation Menu
How to create the navigation menu and open then the click on three vertical dots in the react native app as similar to given image
Click Here to See the image
Given image like exept in react native app and can it possible to create the sub-menu

You can utilise this package as i have used in my projects as well
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-menu
if you need any help to integrate this library let me know

You can use react-native-material-menu package library for this functionality
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-menu
or if you are using react-native-paper there is a option called menu
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/Menu/
